# A query in JAVA NIO Selector?

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I am developing a peer to peer application.
in that each peer has one server socket channel and a socket channel,..
Now i need two selectors to handle the connection for server socket channel and socket channel,...

SelectorProvider seems to be a singleton class and it fices only a single instance of Selector,.. which i cant able to use for both the socket channel,..

is there a way to use two selectors in a single instance of  a program,..

```
private ServerSocketChannel svrScktChnl;
private SocketChannel socketChannel;
```

two selector

```
public Selector selector=null;
public Selector playerSelector=null;
```

i am try to intialize these selector separately one for server socket channel and another for socket channel,..

But i cant initialize once again because it throws an error,,..

Comment: Can you provide the code that is actually throwing an error?

Comment: Unless you have hundreds of connections I would use blocking NIO which means you don't use selectors. Its much simpler and often faster as well.

Comment: If you have to care about `SelectorProvider`, you are doing something really wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now i need two selectors to handle the connection for server socket channel and socket channel,...

No you don't. You can use the same Selector for both, unless for some reason not stated here you want to handle them in separate threads, which is really a violation of everything that NIO stands for.

> SelectorProvider seems to be a singleton class

False. `SelectorProvider.provider()` returns a singleton, but you don't need to use it: there are APIs everywhere that let you specify your own provider. Not that it's relevant, because:

> and it fices only a single instance of Selector

False. I don't know what you mean by 'fices', but `SelectorProvider.openSelector()` returns a new `Selector` every time you call it, which you could have discovered for yourself without the luxurious technique of posting a question here and waiting possibly forever for a possibly incorrect answer, even if the Provider itself was a singleton, which it isn't.

> .. which i cant able to use for both the socket channel,..

No. Clearly you've never actually tried it. You need to understand that this is an empirical science where you are expected to conduct your own experiments. Posting questions on Internet sites and sitting back waiting for the answers is not an efficient use of your time or anybody else's, and it is not calculated to deliver the correct answer as quickly as doing your own work.

> it throws an error

You can't seriously expect anyone to help you with as little information as that. Would you accept that as a bug report from a customer?

Comment: Sorry guys i had a problem in object instantiation,Once i instanitiated the object and used SelectorProvider.openSelector()  all the problems are solved,.. thanks for helping

the problem is not due to selector,...the problem occured because i havent instantiated an object which had the selectors,..without instatiating i tried to assign that selector, which throwed me an exception